# If Morpheus is Neil Gaiman's alter ego, then who really is Daniel Hall?

Tags: neil-gaiman, the-sandman

It is quite common for authors to make  one of their characters as an alter ego of themselves - sometimes this will create an interesting characters like Hermione from HP series (alter ego of Rowling)... and sometimes [Mary Sue](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MarySue) (someone so perfect that its plainly boring).

In case of the "Sandman" series its not hard to notice that there is a stunning similarity between the author - Neil Gaiman and the Morpheus:

[image: Neil Gaiman]
[image: Dream of the Endless]

Same shaggy hair, similar moody behaviour... Of course I can be wrong here But if I am not, then let me follow with another question: Whose alter ego is Daniel Hall then?

> The new Dream, after Morpheus' death

[image: The new Dream of the Endless]

He looks much younger than Morpheus/Neil and has quite different personality than his predecessor. Is he also somehow "related" to his author?

Comment: To my knowledge, it depends on the artist at the time (there's been so many character variations I'd probably need a flow chart to make sense of who was based on who).  Daniel is intended to mirror Morpheus, so an easy answer would be that Daniel is another facet of Neil, just not the Neil we started with.

Comment: For the counterpoint, see Gally's sources [here at the Lit Stack](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/why-does-morpheus-look-like-neil-gaiman) which say Gaiman made certain personality and sartorial choices based on himself but did the original body as a mashup of someone named Peter Murphy and a male ballet dancer.

Comment: The writer of your 'proof' posted there and has little to say by way of 'proof'. There's just the conceit that the Gaiman ended with reference to Shakespeare's supposed last play.

Comment: The 2nd link in the post is now dead.

Comment: @desertnaut - I wonder if the link, which was to a page on the "intellectbooks" site, was to the article ["Mytho-auto-bio: Neil Gaiman’s Sandman, the Romantics and Shakespeare’s The Tempest"](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/intellect/stic/2015/00000006/00000001/art00005) which talks about Morpheus as an alter ego of Gaiman, and was published by Intellect. As far as I can see this is just the author's interpretation though, the article ([available in full on sci-hub](https://sci-hub.se/10.1386/stic.6.1.61_1)) presents no direct confirmation from Gaiman.

Comment: @Hypnosifl yeah, makes sense - it could be